# HttpServletRequest - Get Literal Path

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I have a method marked with Spring's `@RequestMapping` that includes an `HttpServletRequest` method parameter.

If I print out the results of a call to "`request.getServletPath()`" when the path is, say, "`/things/{thingId}`", I will get "`/things/2489sdfjk43298f`," where the `{thingId}` path parameter has been replaced with the actual value.

I want to print out the *literal* request path "`/things/{thingId}`"; I.e. with the curly-braced, un-replaced path parameter "`{thingId}`."

Is this possible in any way?

**Edit:** After looking at Sotirios's second comment below, I realize I may be looking at the problem backward. Here's what I'm actually trying to do...

I am trying to making a single endpoint under "`/**`" that gets the path from the `HttpServletRequest`, which I use to look up a value in an `enum`. This `enum` has several fields, one of which is obviously the aforementioned path, but another is the path of a target JSP file. I then put this path into a `ModelAndView` object and return it to display the page.

This was going just fine until I hit the first endpoint with a path parameter, because I obviously can't place the value "`/things/2489sdfjk43298f`" into the enum, because that will only match for that one specific `thing` with that one specific ID.

So perhaps the actual question would be: How would I do that look-up when parts of the path will change due to path parameters? Is there some sort of wildcard-containing `String` format I can use?

I guess this is turning into more of a `enum`-lookup/`String`-matching question. My bad.

**Edit 2:** Shortened example of the `enum` thing I'm talking about:

```
public enum JspEndpointType {
  HOME("/home", "jsp/home");

  private static final Map<String, String> pathMap;
  private String requestPath;
  private String jspPath;

  static {
    pathMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (JspEndpointType jspEndpointType : JspEndpointType.values()) {
      pathMap.put(jspEndpointType.getRequestPath(), jspEndpointType.getJspPath());
    }
  }

  private JspEndpointValue(String requestPath, String jspPath) {
    this.requestPath = requestPath;
    this.jspPath = jspPath;
  }

  public String getRequestPath() {
    return requestPath;
  }

  public String getJspPath() {
    return jspPath;
  }

  public static String getByRequestPath(String requestPath) {
    return pathMap.get(requestPath);
  }
}
```

Shortened example of my endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
  return new ModelAndView(JspEndpointType.getByRequestPath(request.getServletPath()));
}
```

So things essentially boil down to trying to add to the `enum` a value like this:

```
THINGS("/things/{thingId}", "jsp/things/whatever")
```

..and then being able to pass in the path "`/things/2489sdfjk43298f`" and get back "`/jsp/things/whatever`."

**Edit 3:** I found [this StackoverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137307/reusing-spring-requestmapping-parsing-functionality) which directed me to Spring's [UriComponentsBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html), specifically the "`fromPath`" method. However, that seems to be the reverse of what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already know that it's `{thingId}`. That's a constant in your source code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because it's not a constant in my source code. The `value` attribute in my `@RequestMapping` is the wildcard "`/**`."

Comment: Then there is no placeholder to find. Please clarify.

Comment: Also, path variables are handled by the Spring dispatcher servlet. The servlet API is completely unaware of their existence. This looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, JBNizet Updated the question a bit. Also: It kind of sucks that you can't notify more than one person in a comment.

Comment: It seems you're reinventing Spring's RequestMapping instead of just using it. Why? If you really want that, then you'll have to parse the path and match it with various patterns, the same way Spring does it internally. But really, why reinvent that wheel?

Comment: @JBNizet Because if I don't, I have what I have now: dozens and dozens of `*Controller` classes with hundreds of endpoint methods that are all the exact same code except for the specified path.

Comment: You really should come up with a concrete example. All those "enum-based" mappings should probably indeed be handled by one method, with the enum path field being a path variable. This dynamic one should probably be handled by another method. But without an example, it's hard to understand and to give a concrete advice.

Comment: @JBNizet Updated the question again.

Comment: So, create one ResuestMapping method for all the static stuff, and a second one for the dynamic stuff. Surely the code will be different for the dynamic stuff. Otherwise, what's the point in sending a thingId in the request? Are you building a static site with Spring MVC? Why are all the controllers doing nothing?

Comment: @JBNizet The SpringMVC endpoints return static JSPs that then execute Ajax to fill in any data they might require. The reason for using SpringMVC at all involves the phrases "management mandated" and "I'm not paying you to write session management, SpringMVC has it out of the box, use that."

Comment: If the same view is returned for all the values of thingId, there's really no reason to send the thingId in the request. Just use the same URL to get the view, whatever the thingId is. Then use the thingId to get the data, in the second AJAX request. I do use Spring MVC with angularJS applications, and all my views are static HTML pages.

Comment: @JBNizet After thinking about it and looking at the real system for a bit, I've remembered that the reason we have a path such as "`/things/{thingId}`" is because the path "`/things`" maps to a page listing all `Thing`s, along with their IDs. When you select one of them it takes you to the page for that singular `Thing`, and the Ajax on that resultant page pulls the ID out of the path (that "`/{thingId}`") in order to load that `Thing`.

Answer (score 0):

You may look for the `@RequestMapping` annotation on your own, using reflection.